# Salesforce LWC lightning-card Full height

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I'm having this piece of code which on desktop shows height 100% however on mobile it doesn't

```
<template if:true={displayBrochure}>
    <div class="slds-size_small" style="width:100%;">
        <lightning-card>
            <h3 slot="title"><lightning-icon icon-name="utility:connected_apps" size="small"></lightning-icon>{selectedBrochure.title}</h3>
            <div slot="footer">
                <lightning-button label="Previous" title="Previous"  onclick={previousPage} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button label="Next" title="Next"  onclick={nextPage} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button label="Close" title="Close" icon-name="utility:close" onclick={closeBrochure} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
            </div>
            <div data-id="divDisplay" class="slds-grid_vertical-stretch slds-scrollable_y brochure_scroll_y" lwc:dom="manual" style="width:100%;" ></div>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

.brochure_scroll_y{
overflow-y: scroll !important;
overflow-x: scroll !important;
display:inline-block !important;
max-height:calc(100vh - 300px) !important;
height:calc(100vh - 300px) !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can put the card in `<Lightning:layoutItem>` tag and use flexibility="auto" attribute.

Comment: Hi Farhan, thanks for your reply, but this didn't solve the issue